# Deprecated Functionality: preg_replace(): Passing null to parameter

Tags: magento2, php8

I have an issue;

> 1 exception(s): Exception #0 (Exception): Deprecated Functionality:
> preg_replace(): Passing null to parameter #3 ($subject) of type
> array|string is deprecated in
> /var/www/html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement.php
> on line 222
> Which is ;

```
// get a version of the SQL statement with all quoted
// values and delimited identifiers stripped out
// remove "foo\"bar"
$sql = preg_replace("/\"(\\\\\"|[^\"])*\"/Us", '', $sql);
// get the character for delimited id quotes,
// this is usually " but in MySQL is `
$d = $this->_adapter->quoteIdentifier('a');
$d = $d[0];
// get the value used as an escaped delimited id quote,
// e.g. \" or "" or \`
$de = $this->_adapter->quoteIdentifier($d);
$de = substr($de, 1, 2);
$de = preg_quote($de);
// Note: $de and $d where never used..., now they are:
(222) $sql = preg_replace("/$d($de|\\\\{2}|[^$d])*$d/Us", '', $sql);
return $sql;
}
```

My code is :

```
$_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
$_imagehelper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');
$_product = $block->getProduct();

$specs = $_product->getAttributeText('specifications');
$specs = $specs = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output')- 
>productAttribute($block->getProduct(), $block->getProduct()- 
>getSpecifications(), 'specifications');

$specs = trim( str_replace( array("\r\n","\r", "<br />" ),"", $specs));
$specs = trim( html_entity_decode( $specs ) );
```

Sample output of the my code:

[image]

Comment: Where is preg_replace in the code you provided?

Comment: any update on this? I migrated to a another vps and updated from 2.3.4 to 2.4.5 and PHP7.3 to PHP8.1.
I only got this error in line 222 on the homepage. Thank's in advanced, Edwin

Answer (score 0):

Update below line :

```
$specs = trim( str_replace( array("\r\n","\r", "" ),"", $specs ) );
```

to

```
if($specs){
  $specs = trim( str_replace( array("\r\n","\r", "" ),"", $specs ) );
}
```

Comment: it didnt work ..

Comment: As per your error message, Your 3rd parameter is NULL in str_replace.

Comment: I added a screenshoot of output

Comment: @Gkna how to fix this

Answer (score 0):

It's occurring due to the `$sql` variable being `null`. You need to check `$sql` variable contains a value or not.

Till PHP7.4 this method was runs without any error, from PHP8.1 it throws an error.

To solve this issue please add a `(string)` type for the `$sql` variable.

Please try the below way. I hope It'll not throw any errors.

```
echo $sql = preg_replace("/\"(\\\\\"|[^\"])*\"/Us", '', (string) $sql);
```

Thanks